# How can I use complex type for Conv2d?

Tags: python, pytorch

The official document says that the complex type for Conv2d is supported, but on my environment it says that

```
"Input type (c10::complex<float>) and bias type (float) should be the same"
```

and the code does not work.

I know that Pytorch's model input is usually float32, but the document says it supports complex numbers, so I really want to use it...

My code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

print("Pytorch version")
print(torch.__version__)

m = nn.Conv2d(16, 33, 3, stride=2)

input = torch.randn(20, 16, 50, 100, dtype=torch.float32)
print(m(input))

print("NEXT")
input = torch.randn(20, 16, 50, 100, dtype=torch.complex64)
print(m(input))
```

Result

```
Pytorch version
2.0.1+cu118
tensor([[[[ 2.3293e-01, -3.9820e-01, -9.2724e-02,  ..., -3.7408e-02,
       -5.9544e-01,  1.1753e+00],
      ...,
      [-9.3071e-02, -8.7868e-02,  9.5579e-05,  ...,  7.3185e-01,
        1.3108e+00, -1.6092e-01]]]], grad_fn=<ConvolutionBackward0>)
NEXT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/yyy/230914_learn_prop/test3.py", line 13, in <module>
print(m(input))
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/piptorch20/lib/python3.10/site-    packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/piptorch20/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 463, in forward
return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/piptorch20/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Input type (c10::complex<float>) and bias type (float) should be the same
```

The official document is as follows,
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html

```
This module supports complex data types i.e. complex32, complex64, complex128.
```

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the parameters of your layer to be of complex type:

```py
nn.Conv2d(16, 33, 3, stride=2, dtype=torch.complex64)(torch.ones((1, 16, 3, 3), dtype=torch.complex64))
```

using `dtype`.

If inside a model, you can do `model.type(torch.complex64)` for instance. Not that some operations (such as `relu`) won't be compatible.

Comment: It worked fine!
The instructions you gave me on how to use it with the model is just what I really wanted to hear...
Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped! And indeed, Torch has a nice API for recasting model parameters, that's appreciable.